# Public domain trivia database for game?

Tags: c++, csv

A friend of mine is making a trivia game in C++, and I am asking on his behalf if there are any public domain trivia databases? It should preferably be in a csv style format so that it is easy to parse, but other formats are okay as well as long as the questions are good and the license is public domain? Does anyone have any tips.

Comment: Are you looking for any specific type of questions? I searched online a bit and couldn't find anything immediately, but if you're a) unconcerned with the subject matter of the questions, and b) willing to automate filling out a form and parsing the results, you could try [this site](http://www.gamesforthebrain.com/game/trivia/). That's only a little serious, since I don't know if that would work for that site, but if you literally can find nothing else...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First thing that springs to mind is ye old IRC trivia bots: [archive.org link to irc-wiki.org Trivia questions category](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418134735/http://www.irc-wiki.org/Category:Trivia_questions#Where_can_I_get_these_funky_new_questions.3F)

The content here is licensed by CC, as well as community generated. Not sure if that fits your requirement for 'public domain'.

I'm not sure of the licensing for this one:
http://moxquizz.de/about.html

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a great place to start. It's not public domain, but licensing appears reasonable. I'm accepting this answer. Thank you!